# Cordova Phonegap says android target is missing

Tags: android, cordova, installation, target, phonegap-cli

I'm working on a Phonegap webapp which I want to install on my android device. My Webapp is an working example that doesn't bug on other systems.
I have installed Android SDK. Especially android-22 and android-23 are installed correctly.
`cordova build android` creates a working Android APK that's installed correctly on my device. So android-22 is in fact installed.

But when having connected an android device running `cordova run android` exists with a prompt to install android-22.

```
CordovaError: Please install Android target: "android-22"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got to fix this error by adding the `ANDROID_HOME` variable and setting it to my android-sdk root directory.